Почему при нажатии пропадает курсор и EventClick не срабатывает?
Начал изучать движок, по гайду написал пару строчек которые должны показывать мышь, и разрешать события на клик.
Запускаю, мышь есть, при нажатии вместо события, мышь пропадает как будто я захватил игру.
void AClickerPlayerController::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay(); 
    bShowMouseCursor = true;
    bEnableClickEvents = true;
}



